# Delete cookie in Javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, pageblocktable

I would like to delete my cookie in visualforce using Javascript based on the delid.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script> 
 function deletecook() {
  date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() -2);
    document.cookie = "id=" + '{!delid}' + "; expires=" + date;
     alert(document.cookie);
     }
</script>

<apex:commandLink action="{!delete}" rerender="thePageBlock" onClick="return deletecook();">
                            <apex:param assignTo="{!delid}" value="{!acc.id}"/>

 </apex:commandLink>
```

However, the delid of the cookie does not get deleted. Is there any way I could delete the cookie by the id? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is kind of off-topic, but the correct format would be:

```
document.cookie = '{!delid}=; expires=1970 Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT';
```

Specifying `id={!delid}` specifies that you want to manipulate a cookie named `id`, setting it to `{!delid}`.

There's no need to specify an expiry date that's relative to "now", just use the traditional Unix epoch.

Furthermore, actually, `deletecook()` won't work the way you expect, because onClick occurs before the re-render takes place. You'll probably want to use `onComplete`.

---

Edit: Just do this:

```
<apex:commandLink rerender="thePageBlock"
 onClick="document.cookie='{!acc.id}=; expires=1970 Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT'" />
```

Comment: thanks! Yes I would like to specify id={!delid} so that it will delete that specified id.  Can I just clarify if I were to set the cookie on my controller and delete in visualforce Javascript will it take effect? Because right now I tried deleting, but the cookie keep reappearing on refresh

Comment: Cookies don't have IDs, they have names. The structure of a cookie is `name=value`, so if you want to delete a cookie named `fubar`, by example, you would call `document.cookie="fubar=; expires=1970 Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT"`. Let me add some more code...

Comment: Yeap name=value. But on page refresh the cookie it still there.. :'( Btw I implemented the cookie using this http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/storing-form-field-values-with-the-apex-cookie-class
Weird how on page refresh the cookie is still there.

Comment: @fb69 If I recall correctly, Apex Code managed cookies are protected from JavaScript via HttpOnly, and also prefixed with some value (`apex__`). This means your script can't delete a cookie set by the controller. Only the controller can delete that cookie, and controllers can't access cookies that don't start with `apex__`. You can only delete cookies you create in JavaScript. See [Cookie](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm) for more info.